# Differentiating between a CheckboxTreeViewers CheckStateListener and Selection Listener

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am trying to programmatically determine when a user has clicked a checkbox in a CheckboxTreeViewer vs when they have clicked on the actual object in the tree (i.e. the item displayed directly to the right of the checkbox)

To determine when a checkbox is checked/unchecked I use a CheckStateListener.  This works as expected.

To determine if an object has been clicked I have tried using both a selection listener and a mousedown listener.  Both record that an object has been clicked, as expected.  However, they ALSO record when a checkbox has been checked/unchecked.  I have no way of telling which action (clicking the checkbox vs clicking the object) caused the listener to fire.

Is there a better way to determine what was clicked on by the user?

Thanks!

EDIT. This is the current code I'm testing with (added to an SWT.MouseDown event):

```
private Listener getTestListener() {
    return new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
            final ViewerCell vc = treeViewer.getCell(new 
                Point(event.x, event.y));
            if (vc != null) {
                IStructuredSelection selection = 
                   (IStructuredSelection)treeViewer.getSelection();
                Object selObj = selection.getFirstElement();

                final Object element = vc.getElement();

                // When I click on the checkbox or on the item 
                // to the right of it, the selObj and element 
                // Objects are always the same
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Also tested with Select:
    treeViewer.getTree().addSelectionListener(getTestListener2());
    ...

```
private SelectionListener getTestListener2() {
    return new SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)treeViewer.getSelection();
            Object selObj = selection.getFirstElement();
        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        }
    };
}
```

Which also yielded the same results between e and selObj

UPDATE:

I had to make a horrendous workaround where I get the event.x value, the level of the tree node and do OS-specific math to determine if the mouse was over a checkbox or not.  I wish there were a better way...

Comment: one thing that will help is to analyze the event source object from the action event.

Comment: I have done that via debugger and there is no relevant information I can find.  Do you have any specifics you may know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the current selection from the table rather than the selection change event that does not seem to change when the selection event is for clicking the check box.

So it will be empty or the previously selected element and will not match the selection you get from the event.

This is testing on Mac OS X. I'm not sure if this behavior applies to all platforms.

You can get the current selection from the tree or table viewer with something like:

```
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)viewer.getSelection();

Object selObj = selection.getFirstElement();
```

Comment: How will I know when to check the current selection from the table? I'd assume that would require a listener?

Comment: Also, I am not sure where the table is... I am currently setting the listener via treeViewer.getTree().addListener().  This does not give me the desired results

Comment: No, you just call `treeViewer.getSelection()`

Comment: I think I'm confused. Where does the code block shown in your example get called?  Wouldn't a listener have to trigger it?  If not, how would one know when to explicitly call it?

Comment: In your selection listener you can look at the selection from `treeViewer.getSelection` and the selection from `SelectionChangedEvent.getSelection` and see if they are the same or different

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  Ill give it a shot and report back!

Comment: I posted a code snippet in the original message.  Would you mind visually giving it a lookover to see if we're talking about the same thing?  If we are talking about the same thing, then the suggested workaround does not work in Linux.

Comment: I think it looks ok. As I said this behavior probably depends on the native controls being used so may vary between platforms. From the sound of it there is may be no way to distinguish the events on Linux.

Comment: That's bad news to hear. I figure people would want such basic functionality and this should have been addressed long ago.  I made a workaround (see original post), but really wish I didn't have to.